# Live stream the screen and microphone to azure media services with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, live-streaming, azure-media-services

I'm able to stream a video of my screen to Azure Media Services with ffmpeg, but when I add the audio input, the stream stops with this error:

```
ffmpeg: frame=   27 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=   8.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.703x
ffmpeg: frame=   43 fps= 42 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=   8.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.356x    
ffmpeg: frame=   58 fps= 38 q=27.0 size=      37kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate= 818.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.24x    
ffmpeg: av_interleaved_write_frame(): End of file
ffmpeg:     Last message repeated 1 times
ffmpeg: [flv @ 0633fec0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
ffmpeg: [flv @ 0633fec0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
ffmpeg: Error writing trailer of rtmp://rtmpurl/stream: End of file
ffmpeg: frame=   59 fps= 32 q=26.0 Lsize=      37kB time=00:00:00.39 bitrate= 764.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=7 speed=0.214x    
ffmpeg: video:35kB audio:2kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:18.27  size: 30491
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] frame P:16    Avg QP:20.68  size:  4210
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] frame B:42    Avg QP:23.25  size:   152
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] consecutive B-frames:  5.1%  0.0%  0.0% 94.9%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] mb I  I16..4: 12.7% 36.9% 50.4%
Ffmpeg Exited
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  1.0%  0.6%  P16..4: 45.6% 10.5% 12.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:29.8%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 15.5%  0.3%  0.0%  direct: 0.3%  skip:83.9%  L0:46.5% L1:51.0% BI: 2.5%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] 8x8 transform intra:41.1% inter:59.1%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 79.9% 96.5% 88.6% inter: 7.8% 15.8% 5.4%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 20% 13%  6% 61%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 21% 22%  4%  4%  5%  3%  3%  8%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 38% 16% 10%  5%  7%  7%  5%  6%  6%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 54% 18% 23%  5%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] ref P L0: 55.1%  2.9% 29.5% 12.6%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] ref B L0: 79.5% 14.0%  6.6%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] ref B L1: 93.2%  6.8%
ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0633c6c0] kb/s:333.49
ffmpeg: Conversion failed!
```

My ffmpeg command is:

```
-f dshow -i audio="Microphone device" -strict -2 -c:a aac -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 161 -offset_y 203 -video_size 430x322 -show_region 1 -i title="Window Title" -b:v 415K -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -b:a 32K -ar 22050 -filter:a "volume=0.8" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset medium -bufsize 400k -maxrate 400k -f flv rtmp://rtmpurl/stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I don't know why, but if I put the video input in front of the audio input, works fine.
This is my fixed command, it's still not perfect, but it works:

```
-f gdigrab -framerate 30 -offset_x 161 -offset_y 203 -video_size 430x322 -show_region 1 -i title="Window Title" -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Device" -strict -2 -c:a aac -b:v 415K -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -b:a 32K -ar 22050 -filter:a "volume=0.6499733" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset medium -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 4000k -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize rtmp://rtmpurl/stream
```